# Рост времени отклика сервера (Waiting (TTFB)) при частых AJAX запросах

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, запрос, время

С главной страницы сайта отправляю POST/GET (без разницы, проблема при любом типе запроса) запросы на другую страницу. Например с на странице 'index.php' есть JS скрипт, который содержит AJAX запрос. Этот AJAX запрос посылается на страницу 'game_core.php'. При первом запросе POST время отклика равно ~110ms, а если запросы ежесекундно повторять со стороны клиента на сервер, то время отклика сервера Waiting (TTFB) растёт, причем после каждого последующего запроса чуть ли не вдвое. Из-за чего предыдущий запрос не успевает выполниться, а следующий уже отправлен. В итоге сайт становится недоступным для любого пользователя до того момента, пока сервер не обработает все запросы.
Вот пример запроса:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'game_core.php',
            data: {
                тут мои данные
            },
            success: {
                здесь мой код
            }
        });
```

Как я понимаю, для работы AJAX запросов нужна jQuery, которая так же у меня присутствует и подключена до самого скрипта с запросами.
Следует понимать, что первый запрос должен выполняться за свои ~100ms, а последующий, содержащий такой же объем данных, который поступает уже после выполнения первого запроса должен иметь время отклика тоже ~100ms, но у меня это время увеличивается при частых запросах, и сервер (сайт) падает.

Comment: растет время серверной обработки запросов? "Shlemiel gets a job as a street painter ..." - https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: Тут ошибка скорее всего в бакенде. Поэтому нужно смотреть ваш код на сервере. Или проблема может быть в БД. @Igor *Every day I get farther and farther away from the paint can!*

Comment: Я понял, из-за чего растёт время запросов. Мой сайт использует HTTPS протокол, а запросы HTTP. Чтобы исправить проблему, нужно использовать WebSocket. Но теперь другая проблема, сервер не понимает WebSocket и возвращает код 200.
Вот так я подключаю WebSocket: 
       
    `var socket = new WebSocket("ws://javascript.ru/ws");`